# ORA-01950 error during the execution of insert statement

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

```
SQL> insert into DEPT values(101, 'RAMESH');
insert into DEPT values(101, 'RAMESH')
        *
```

> ERROR at line 1:
>
> ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'USERS'

I cant sort the above problem?

Answer (score 3):

This is already asked on [ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'USERS' [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671008/ora-01950-no-privileges-on-tablespace-users/21671145#21671145). It was answered as:

You cannot insert data because you have a quota of 0 on the tablespace. To fix this, run

```
ALTER USER <user> quota unlimited on <tablespace name>;
```

or

```
ALTER USER <user> quota 100M on <tablespace name>;
```

as a DBA user (depending on how much space you need / want to grant).